# new tag for newsstand icon

Tags: iphone, icons, newsstand-kit

As we know , when we receive a push notification with newsstand or my server had publish a new magazine, the newsstand shelf will show the newsstand icon of my app with a new tag, my question is : the new tag is auto made by Apple or by me when add a newsstand issue ?
if new tag is aotu made by Apple , if the localized language is chinese or japanese, the "New" tag will be changed "新规" or other local words? Thank you very much!

[image]

Answer (score 0):

To add the "New" badge,

```
UIApplication *app = [UIApplication sharedApplication];
[app setApplicationIconBadgeNumber:[app applicationIconBadgeNumber]+1];
```